# Windows 10 Skype freezes when using keyboard layout shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

I have **Windows 10** installed on my machine. I am using the keyboard shortcuts for switching between keyboard languages(layouts). For instance, I use `Ctrl+1` to switch to my primary language.

If I press Ctrl+1 inside **Skype**, Skype starts to die slowly and painfully. It just becomes `Not responding` and hangs like this forever until killed.

I am used to switch languages like this too strong. It is too strange and Microsoft should feel ashamed for not being able to test two of it's greatest products together.

**In order to reproduce:**

1. Use Windows 10
2. Download Skype latest version. I use `7.21.0.100`
3. Right click The Language Bar (in the bottom-right corner, next to the clock) -> Settings.
4. Click Advanced Settings
5. Click `Change language bar hotkeys` (under the section `Switching input methods`).
6. Add a key sequence for any language you want.
7. Inside Skype, press the key sequence you set before.
8. *Skype will hang* Close it with the *Task Manager*

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tested and confirmed that actually it's a bug ? I mean from other machines etc?

Comment: @SeanClt No, I did not. I did, however, a clean reinstall of Windows and Skype. Skype hangs every single time, with any keyboard shortcut set.

Comment: So how do you know it's not just you it could be specific to your machine your hardware or graphic card

Comment: You should add step step instructions so somebody else can confirm if it's actually an issue

Comment: Unless a second person can confirm its just your HO not a bug

Comment: @SeanClt See an update :)

Comment: If you google for "skype hangs language hot key windows 10", you'll see several links to the Skype Community site, with the same bug described. There are 'solutions', like setting compatibility mode, but they don't work for me. The issue exists for more than a year, BTW.

Comment: @AlexChe The saddest thing is, Windows 10 and Skype both are Microsoft's products and the bug report have been submitted several times since Windows 10 release. That's very irresponsible from their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by installing Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/571113)

Comment: @burgi Why is this not an answer?

Comment: @burgi Thanks, I've edited my post to make it answer the question.

Comment: Wow thank you! Installing this update helped. Took them a year to fix it though..

Comment: @DavidPostill it doesn't explain *why* this particular update fixes the issue.

Comment: @burgi, usually an update fixes some issue, because developers address the issue in their code, and the code changes find it's way to the new product updated packages. I did not add this to my answer, because not only it's obvious, but also it does not add anything useful to the answer. At the same time I still think that the answer itself is useful, because it gives at least one possible way to fix the issue. If you have concrete ideas of how this answer can be improved, please let me know.